# How do I play an audio clip from a https URL in Qt6 on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg

I keep getting the following error:

```
https protocol not found, recompile FFmpeg with openssl, gnutls or securetransport enabled
```

I link **OpenSSL** in my project, I also have **OpenSSL** Toolkit installed through the Qt Maintenance Tool, however that doesn't seem to fix it.

I have also found an answer online, that said that I need to copy the **OpenSSL** DLLs to my build folder, but that didn't work either.

I use Qt 6.5.0.

Do I have to compile Qt on my own? or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

I worked around that by setting the QT_MEDIA_BACKEND environment variable to windows.

After adding

```
putenv("QT_MEDIA_BACKEND=windows");
putenv("QT_MULTIMEDIA_PREFERRED_PLUGINS=directshow");
```

to my code and it works fine.